# How to get AVPlayer buffer time needed before playback was started

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to measure how long an `AVPlayerItem` buffered before it began playback.

A trivial solution for this would be to simply start a timer/save a timestamp when buffering begins, and stop the timer/compare the timestamps either when `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` first becomes positive, or use `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes` with a 1ms boundary.

Since this is something I want to use in a production environment (to track performance metrics), I prefer not to start a bunch of timers that could potentially bring down app performance.

Is there a way to achieve this by using KVO or some other method?

Comment: Is it a live stream? did you check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1389386-duration?language=objc) parameter?

Comment: Yes I am using HLS. The duration property simply gives you the duration of the file being played, correct me if I am wrong here. I am looking for how long the video was buffering for before it began playing.

Comment: unfortunately `duration` parameter from `AVPlayerItem` will always return `kCMTimeIndefinite `. Need to dig into apple documentation

Comment: AFAIK we can't get the duration before the status changes into ready to play. 

This is what I got it from apple documentation `To get the duration of a streaming item, you can observe the duration property on the player item. When the item becomes ready to play, this property updates to the correct value for the stream.`

Comment: for more info check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW3)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not interested in the duration of the item. I am simply interested in how long the item needed to buffer before it decided to begin playing.